# How to concenate multiple lists in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I was wondering wether the following would be possible with Neo4j.

Suppose I have a class of nodes, say (event:Event) whereas every Event has a tags property ([String]).
Now I can return all those arrays just fine like:

```
MATCH (event:Event) RETURN event.tags
```

However I don't understand yet how I could combine the output for the different node results to be collected in one list. Is such a thing possible with Cypher? Of course one could always programatically solve this thing, but as far as I understand Cypher offers reduce as well as native list addition.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you can use [APOC library](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures) use `flatten` function for collections:

```
MATCH (event:Event) 
RETURN apoc.coll.flatten(COLLECT(event.tags))
```

`COLLECT(event.tags)` will combine all results into single list (list of lists of tags)

`apoc.coll.flatten(..)` will flatten the list of lists into single list

If for some reason you can't use APOC, use `reduce`:

```
MATCH (event:Event) 
RETURN REDUCE(s = [], tags IN COLLECT(event.tags) | s + tags)
```

Comment: What's the reason for recommending `apoc.coll.flatten(..)` over `REDUCE`? I would have assumed that the builtin `REDUCE` would be faster than the APOC procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Map Projection may do most of what you're asking.

[map projection documentation](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/syntax/maps/)
You can start with a node and add to it.

```
MATCH (user:User)-[:TRIGGERED]->(event:Event) WITH event {.*, user_id:user.user_id} as user_event
```

This would give you an array of events with the added parameter of user_id.

Comment: Hello @Eric. This is not what the question intended to ask, it was specifically about list reduction. However I have read further on map projection and find it very useful for other use cases, thank you for linking it!